# How to stop ionic cordova run android command delete existing ionic apps on the device

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to the forum and need help on running/installing ionic 3 app on a real device.

1. This command: ionic cordova run android (in my case) will delete the existing ionic app being installed on the device even though the app names are different.
2. I'd tried using ionic cordova run android `--prod --release` but the result is the same, i.e. Only ONE ionic app will be installed on the Android device which doesn't sound right.
3. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?  Any options?  Below is my package.json file:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
       "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
       "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
       "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
       "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
       "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
       "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
       "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
       "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
       "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
       "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
       "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
       "ionicons": "3.0.0",
       "rxjs": "5.5.2",
       "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
       "zone.js": "0.8.18"
     },
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the package name of that App? This issue happened when package name of Apps are same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Correct me if I'm wrong.  A package (same name) "android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk" will be generated after the command ionic cordova --run.  So do you mean I need to rename this android-release-unsigned.apk package and then use the keytool and jarsigner for signing the package.  Then re-run the ionic cordova --run again ?  Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly is want and where you getting stuck

Comment: My problem is each time I issue the command ionic cordova --run the app will overwrite whatever installed on the Android device (phone).  E.g. if an Ionic app ABC was ran and installed.  Then if I worked on another app e.g. 123, run the ionic cordova --run command again.  It will erase the ABC app previous installed on the Android device.

Comment: Thank you suniel kalwani.  Problem solved by changing the default package name.

Comment: i am glad its helps you .please mark my answer as correct .